# Why the execution time of a loop is not proportional to the size of the loop

Tags: r, performance, loops

I wrote this "bad" function (volontary slow) to build a vector and testing the execution time :

```
f <- function(n){
  vec <- c()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    vec <- c(vec, i)
  }
}
```

I thought that if I multiply the size of the loop by 10 then the execution time of the function would increase proportionately. But we can see that the execution time is not proportional at all and even very superior :

```
> system.time(f(1e+04))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
0.14        0.00        0.14 
> system.time(f(1e+05))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
13.35        0.00       13.49 
> system.time(f(1e+06))

Timing stopped at: 1322.7 0.29 1338.59
```

Maybe it's a basic computing notion but I wonder why the execution time of this loop (but I think it's the same thing for loops in general) is not proportional to the size of the loop ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by incrementally growing an object. Each time you increase the size of the object (`vec <- c(vec, i)`) a new place has to be allocated in memory for the new object. This involves allocating a new set of memory, and copying the old object plus the new part into the newly allocated space. When the object grows, this operation becomes more and more expensive. This explains why the time does not grow linearly but exponentially: the allocate-copy step is not linear in the size of the newly allocated space, thus the run time is also not linear with the size of the loop.